# Permissions to Start a Bundle workflow

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1, permissions

We are using Workflow on the Bundles with Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. Our requirement is, *when User(Content Editor/Author) creates/updates any content; he must put it in a bundle and start a workflow on it for auditing.*

But the *User can not start a Workflow if he doesn't have "workflow Management" rights*. We have tested it on Bundles with and without content. Also, the content is editable by the User.

[image]

We don't want to give "Workflow Management" privileges to the User as it enables the Workflow Management Panel under Administration for the user and he can control everything related to the Workflow in the system.

Is it a must to have "Workflow Management" rights to start a workflow or there is some ways to achieve it without those rights?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the error you are getting in case the user does not have Workflow Management Rights?

Comment: stack trace, you mean from the browser console ??

Comment: No, I mean the stack trace from the Error message in the Tridion Event Log on the CM server.

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure users do not *need* the Workflow Management right in order to start workflow.

Some things to check:

- Workflow settings in the context of the Publication the Bundle is created in (set `Enable Workflow Process Associations in Shared Schemas and Structure Groups` if you want to share the settings)
- If the user has at least read access in the context of the Bundle
- Items are not locked (checked out or in workflow already)

Awhile back I made a [simple bundle workflow tutorial](https://community.sdl.com/solutions/content-management/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/setting-up-sdl-tridion-multi-item-workflow-with-bundles) for other things to check.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I have checked the 3 points you mentioned and the answer is "yes" for all the points.

Comment: Okay, continue by looking at the Event Log as @Rick suggested. It might be something else, but "permissions" in a Tridion context implies issues (with read, write, delete, or localize) in terms of organizational items.